# c# Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I am trying to connect MySQL database on remote host `htttp://www.tasiheel.com`.

This is my code

```
try
    {
     string addClientQuery = "insert into clients values(null,@name,@sender,@user,@pass,@date)";
     MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("Server=http://tasiheel.com;Database=xxxxxx;Uid=xxxx;Pwd=xxxxx;");

     MySqlCommand addClientCmd = new MySqlCommand(addClientQuery, conn);
     addClientCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", clinetNameTXT.Text);
     addClientCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("sender", senderNameTXT.Text);

     addClientCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("user", userNameTXT.Text);
     addClientCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pass", userPassTXT.Text);
     addClientCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("date", DateTime.Now);
     conn.Open();
     addClientCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     RadMessageBox.Show("تم اضافة البيانات بنجاح");
     }
 catch (MySqlException ex)
     {
     MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
     }
```

but I got the following error when trying to open connection

> Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts

I can access the databse form php page on the server, but I can't from c# winform

I have enabled the remote database access by adding `%` to database privileges.

Any help for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to enter the IP of the remote server in the connectionstring as described in another answer.

Make sure your MySQL (where it has installed) allow remote connection. If database is on same server as code, you should better use localhost as Server (this will also save round trip to own server)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your connection string:

From:

```
Server=http://tasiheel.com;Database=xxxxxx;Uid=xxxx;Pwd=xxxxx;
```

To

```
Server=http://tasiheel.com;Port=3306;Database=xxxxxx;User ID=xxxx;Password=xxxxx;
```

Comment: Check your firewall settings

You may need to add an exception for port 3306 . Also i added Port parameter to connection string. see Answer.

Comment: i disabled the firewall and add the port but still getting the same error

Comment: yes i ping the ip from c# and it response for ping i try to put it instead of domain name but no thing changed the same problem